# Sort by none/disable auto-arrange in Explorer doesn't exist or does not work

Tags: sorting

Unchecking Sort By "Name" seems to be disabled.  Is there any way around this?

This is EXTREMELY limiting and frustrating in Windows 10, in fact, anything past Vista. No matter what I do to effect a free sorting (aligned with the grid, closing gaps left (as with icons in Android systems) it reverts with every refresh or when closing/reopening a window. .bat and .reg tweaks have little to no effect

Why has Microsoft removed this functionality in Windows 10? It is probably one of the most useful features for non-linear thinkers, artists, graphic designers and those suffering from ADHD. This is preventing me from working properly!

I wrote to them kindly asking them if they would please consider introducing a "Sort by None" into the context menu of folders, a toggle switch to enable/disable the "Sort by" feature, or a manual override that the system does not simply take over.  However, I've received no response.

The great advantage that Windows has over Apple Mac is that it is highly customizable. Why on earth would Microsoft become despotic and refuse this exceptionally useful function, thereby diminishing one of its greatest marketplace advantages?

I have managed to enable a free-sorting functionality/disable auto arrange but it reverts each time I refresh the Explorer Window or close it down and reopen it.  It is as if Windows 10 OS chooses to ignore or discard my manual ordering and in the View Menu of Explorer, there is no way to uncheck "Name" in the Sort By view.  Can someone help me stop the OS from overriding my individual choices in this regard, please?